# Check multiple checkboxes using jQuery from two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array like

```
var favorite = {};
    $.each($(".list input[type='checkbox']:checked"), function(){ 
        if(typeof(favorite[$(this).attr("name")]) == 'undefined'){
            favorite[$(this).attr("name")] = [];
        }           
        favorite[$(this).attr("name")].push($(this).val());
    });
```

With one dimensional array I can do:

```
$('#list [value="'+favorite.join('"],[value="')+'"]').prop('checked',true);
```

Which produces a selector like:

```
$('#list [value="1"],[value="3"],[value="4"],[value="5"]')
```

But how can I produce a selector from two dimensional array like:

```
$('#list [Name="Name[]",value="1"],[Name="Name[]",value="3"],[Name="Name[]",value="4"],[Name="Model[]",value="5"]')
```

I need to select all checkboxes which is in favorite array. Because after ajax Post I lose all checked checkboxes something like that:

```
$(function() {
    $('.list input').change(function(e){
            //e.preventDefault();
            var favorite = {};
                $.each($(".list input[type='checkbox']:checked"), function(){ 
                    if(typeof(favorite[$(this).attr("name")]) == 'undefined'){
                        favorite[$(this).attr("name")] = [];
                    }           
                    favorite[$(this).attr("name")].push($(this).val());
                });


        var str;
        str = $.param(favorite);
        
        $.ajax({
            url:'/Search.asp',
            type:'POST',
            data:str,
            dataType:'text',
            success: function(data)
            {
                $("#ExSearchForm").html(data);
                $("#ExSearchForm").find('[value=' + favorite.join('], [value=') + ']').prop("checked", true);
            }
        });
        

    });
});
```

The Html markup

```
                <div class="list">
                    <div class="nomination">Make</div>
                    <div class="name">
                    <label class='selected-car'><input type='checkbox' name='Make[]' value='*FAKE*' /><span>*FAKE*<i>0</i></span></label>
<label class='selected-car'><input type='checkbox' name='Make[]' value='AIXAM' /><span>AIXAM<i>2</i></span></label>
<label class='selected-car'><input type='checkbox' name='Make[]' value='ALFA ROMEO' /><span>ALFA ROMEO<i>106</i></span></label>
<label class='selected-car'><input type='checkbox' name='Make[]' value='ALPINA' /><span>ALPINA<i>1</i></span></label>
<label class='selected-car'><input type='checkbox' name='Make[]' value='AUDI' /><span>AUDI<i>686</i></span></label>
<label class='selected-car'><input type='checkbox' name='Make[]' value='BMW' /><span>BMW<i>557</i></span></label>
....
```

Comment: I dont think the last selector is valid. It wont work

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a *lot* more complicated than it needs to be. Can you describe what you are trying to achieve so we can show you a more efficient way.

Comment: $(".list input[type='checkbox']:checked") already return your checked input as jquery object,
saving this into a var and use it later $("#ExSearchForm").find(myvar).prop("checked", true); should do the trick

Comment: `$("#ExSearchForm").find(myvar)` will not work beause of DOM will be completely updated after POST success. So, references to the elements will be cleared too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create array of values based on `favorite` object:

```
$('.list input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
    var favorite = {};

    $('.list input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
        var $el = $(this);
        var name = $el.attr('name');
        if (typeof (favorite[name]) === 'undefined') {
            favorite[name] = [];
        }
        favorite[name].push($el.val());
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Search.asp',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $.param(favorite),
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#ExSearchForm").html(data)
                .find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                    var $el = $(this);
                    var name = $el.attr('name');
                    var value = $el.attr('value')
                    if (favorite[name] && favorite[name].indexOf(value) !== -1) {
                        $el.prop('checked', true);
                    }
                });
        }
    });
});
```

Notice: But such kind of selectors are very complicated and could be extremely slow.

Comment: This selector is similar to your (it can be slow in case if there are thousands of checkboxes).

Comment: But the snippet will be little faster in gerenal than your. Because it caches references to checkbox elements inside `each` loop and form reference inside `success` callback.

Comment: This example should be pretty fast. Just try it.

Comment: It was a typo mistake. Just replace `a` by `favorite`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80178/discussion-between-taras-romaniv-and-dmitrij-holkin).

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=Make[]] and Your code select all checkbox not which is selected

Comment: Please look updated answer! I think .find need also `[value=`

Comment: Why not use something like  `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(favorite).forEach(function(val, idx, array) { print(val + ' -> ' + obj[val]);});` ?

Comment: `for` loops are much faster

Comment: But i need Name= Name[] too not only value= as i have a lot of different name= and then value= can be an duplicate

Comment: The latest update should be working. Also I've createa a JSPerf test http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-by-name . So it uses the fastest approach.

Comment: Also i need attach to thoose check boxes all dropdowns (<select><option></option>)

Comment: What i need hold not only checked checkboxes but also selected values in dropdowns, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758943/combine-checkedcheckboxes-with-selected-dropdown-values

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an array of objects instead then you can easily iterate over that array which would also be significantly faster.

Something like this

```js
$(function() {
    $('.list input').change(function(e){
            //e.preventDefault();
            var favorite = {};
                $.each($(".list input[type='checkbox']:checked"), function(){ 
                    if(typeof(favorite[$(this).attr("name")]) == 'undefined'){
                        var item = {
                          value: 1, 
                          name : favorite[$(this).attr("name")
                        }
                    } else {
                        var item = {
                          value: 0, 
                          name : favorite[$(this).attr("name")
                        }
                    }
                                          
                    favorite[$(this).attr("name")].push(item);
                               
                    
                });

    });
});
```

Comment: You can not use array of objects because `favorite` should be serialized later using `$.param` and passed as param to the `$.ajax`

Comment: Objects can be serialized too?